# JS errors in checkout and the page can't stop loading

Tags: checkout, javascript, jquery, magento2.2.2, bug

On a fresh installation **M 2.2.2**, checkout page can't load some JS files, and the page cannot stopping loading, I tried to insert them manually but no success !

[image]

Comment: Have you deploy static content?

Comment: @Suresh Chikani  yes indeed, Im in developper mode so the `static-contents` will be deployed automatically but I did it too `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` but nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

Try below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR en_Us -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: it didn't solve the problem !

Comment: Which language is used in store?

Comment: ........`fr_FR`

Comment: check my updated command.

Comment: The same problem @Suresh Chikani :(

Comment: I just notice that if I change the `luma-child` by the `luma`, I haven't the problem, an idea?